# jQuery Ajax timing loop issue with setInterval / onAnimationStopped using flipCounter

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have the code as per below. This retrieves some data to use for the counter including a variable for the reload interval - this is NOT used below in order to rule out an issue with the data retrieval, I have hard coded a 10 second interval instead but the problem remains.

All works fine for the intial page load and also for one interval, then everything goes haywire, the calls are made with no delay and the counter cannot react before the next call is made, both the onAnimationStopped and the setInterval appear to be ignored eventually leading to a total hang.

There is some sort of a loop happening somewhere but despite trawling for a few hours none of the answers I have found related to setInterval/Ajax calls answer this issue.

Please note I have also tried setTimeout but this exhibits identical behaviour.

Any help appreciated.

(Only tested using FF and Chrome at present - same issue in both).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flipCounter.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="counter">
<input type="hidden" name="counter-value" value="0" />
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
            jQuery(document).ready(doAjax());

                    function doAjax()
                    {   
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "counterData.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data){
                                doTheCounter(data);
                                }
                        })
                    }

                    function doTheCounter(data)
                    {   

                        var scrollfromnumber = data.scrollfromnumber;
                        var displaynumber = data.displaynumber;
                        var reloadinterval = data.reloadinterval;

                        jQuery("#counter").flipCounter({
                            number: scrollfromnumber,
                            numIntegralDigits:6,
                            numFractionalDigits:0
                        });

                        jQuery("#counter").flipCounter("startAnimation", {
                            end_number: (displaynumber),
                            easing:jQuery.easing.easeInOutCubic,
                            duration:5000,
                            onAnimationStopped: function(){
                                setInterval(doAjax,10000);
                                }
                        });
                    }
        /* ]]> */
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When working with jQuery AJAX you should use the complete function `complete: function(data){ doTheCounter(data); }` This will ensure that your next method is not run until after the AJAX call is fully completed.  Also, any time that you are using an animation you might try using a callback function to run after the animation i.e. `.animation('someanimation',params,callbackFunction(){})` It would help if you would post the flipCounter() code.

Comment: http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not send ajax requests or start animations with a `setInterval`, `setInterval` doesn't allow for slow browsers/networks or network connection failures. Use `setTimeout` instead.

Also, `$(document).ready(doAjax());` should be `$(document).ready(doAjax);`

```
jQuery(document).ready(doAjax);

function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "counterData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            doTheCounter(data);
        }
    })
}

function doTheCounter(data) {

    var scrollfromnumber = data.scrollfromnumber;
    var displaynumber = data.displaynumber;
    var reloadinterval = data.reloadinterval;

    jQuery("#counter").flipCounter({
        number: scrollfromnumber,
        numIntegralDigits: 6,
        numFractionalDigits: 0
    });

    jQuery("#counter").flipCounter("startAnimation", {
        end_number: (displaynumber),
        easing: jQuery.easing.easeInOutCubic,
        duration: 5000,
        onAnimationStopped: function() {
            setTimeout(doAjax,10000);
        }
    });
}
```

The reason your code fails with setInterval is because you never cleared the previous interval, you just started another one every time, so first you sent one request, then 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc. until the browser crashes.

**UPDATE:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(doAjax);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#counter").flipCounter({
        number: 0,
        numIntegralDigits: 6,
        numFractionalDigits: 0
    });
});   

function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "counterData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            doTheCounter(data);
        }
    })
}

function doTheCounter(data) {

    var scrollfromnumber = data.scrollfromnumber;
    var displaynumber = data.displaynumber;
    var reloadinterval = data.reloadinterval;

    jQuery("#counter").flipCounter("startAnimation", {
        end_number: (displaynumber),
        easing: jQuery.easing.easeInOutCubic,
        duration: 5000,
        onAnimationStopped: function() {
            setTimeout(doAjax,10000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, sorry I should have been clearer, I did try setTimeout too but it causes the exact same behaviour. "2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64"  ....that's definitely what's happening though.

Comment: If it is still doing "2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64", i suspect the flipCounter plugin is firing on animation stopped multiple times, I don't see from the current logic where it could be queuing up multiple times.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `async: false`?

Comment: "async: false" - I put this in there as have seen this as an answer on other posts for similar issues so it was to ensure this wasn't suggested as an answer. It was explained that ajax being asynchronous would not obey timeOut commands as by definition they are 'outside of time' but I think in the context they are being called this is irrelevant as the call is made inside of time. I think you're right about it being something to do with the flipCounter plug in.

Comment: I would attempt to find a way to only initialize the flipCounter once, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect, just needed to add "number: (scrollfromnumber)," to the start of the flipcounter startAnimation(). Many thanks for your help.